# Entity Framework: EF always saves values "on top" of old values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC Application where I use Entity Framework, I discovered a strange behavior while saving. I have a view, where I check if customers in the data base exist, if thats true, they will be displayed with their data in a table. Works fine. The user can add more customers to the table, to illustrate that, a small Example:

Database contains the customers John and Jim. They are displayed in the table. The user adds 2 customers to the table: Peter and Jack, so now the table should contain the customers: John, Jim, Peter and Jack.

So what happens now is, when I save them in my controller. The customers that are saved, are John, Jim, John, Jim, Peter and Jack. Entity Framework seems to add those on top, of the customers before, but thats not what I want, I just want to save those customers, like they are displayed in the table. I hope you can help me out on this.

Here is the code in my controller to save the customers:

```
var counter = 0;
string customerName = "";

while (true)
{
customerName = Request.Form["CustomerName[" + counter + "]"];
if (customerName == "" || customerName == null)
{
   break;
}
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.OverviewID = CustomerOverview.ID;
customer.Name = customerName;
db.Customer.Add(customer);
db.SaveChanges();
counter++;
}
```

Here is how I add the existing customers to the table in the view:

```
@{
    if (Model.Customers.Count() > 0)
    {

        foreach (var customer in Model.Cusomters)
        {
            <text>ArrayCustomers.push("@(customer.Name)");</text>
        }
    }
    else
    {
            <text>ArrayCustomers.push("");</text>
    }
}
    refresh_table();
```

Comment: How they are displayed in the table depends on how your table constructed and on what RDBMS you're using. to display them the way you want just use `OrderBy`

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is not strange at all. Your code says "For each name in the form, add the name you see there." Your form lists the names of two entries that are already there - probably in form fields. So you have your code populate your first two form fields (instead of you doing it manually) when the page loads, and then you type in the other two names, and EF simply adds each one, a total of 4 names. So your DB ends up with 6 names, and 2 duplicates.

The way to avoid this is not load the names you already have into form fields. That way they don't get submitted when you click the submit button. You should `@DisplayFor` for items you're merely displaying on your page, and `@EditorFor` for items you want to add.

Related to your question - I'm not sure why you're not following the regular MVC pattern, but it will add to your misery if you don't. You don't list what your form html code looks like, which probably contributed to your question getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an id for each customer in the table that already exists. Then, you will ask if the customer is already saved or you could filter if the customer has an id. If customer has not an id, then it is new so you save it.

As you are using mvc, I would suggest you post a collection of customers and use model binding, instead of getting values out of the request.